An american (natural?) disaster movie from 5 to 10 years ago
It is one of these End-of-the-world movies, there were several in roughly the same period, and the only scene I know to be from this film is a "V.I.P. pick-up scene".
The woman is (iirc) one of the main characters. I seem to recall there also being a big-name known male action actor in one of the other lead roles.
The scene features some men in government suits waking (i think) a woman up, then they briefly talk at her door. She is told, she has no choice but to come with them. She is some sort of scientist, iirc. Then you see them driving on an empty highway. She asks about the exact reason for picking her up, and is informed, that the pick-up-crew does not know.
She notices that the highway is devoid of cars, and then there is an exchange like:

"Where are all the cars?"
"The Highway was cleared"
"Why was the highway cleared?"
"For you, Ma'am"

I hope this is enough information to go on.

don't know why but for some reason the first thing that popped into my head when I read that was Deep Impact back in 1998 I think

The Day the Earth Stood Still (2008)
Here is a clip from the movie, it starts with the conversation in question:



EDIT: It seems that the clip can be watched on Youtube only. The uploader doesn't allow to watch it if embedded on other sites. 
Government agent knocks on Dr. Benson's door:

Dr. Benson, if you come with us.
What's happening?
Everything will be explained en route.
Where are all the cars?
We shut down the highway.
You shut it down? For what?
For us.

